# Backlinks - Should I Disavow SEO, Keyword, Performance, Stats, Domain, and Other Similar Sites?

Tags: backlinks, directory, disavow-links

So it's obvious in the new era that we should disavow poor quality backlinks. What about links from sites like that are intended to provide "statistical or performance information"? Most of them seem pretty poor quality but are "respectable" and used enough by people. Allow or Disavow - how do you deal with these?

Some random examples of ones that make followed backlinks:

- alexa.com (included for completeness of this thought)
- m.biz
- dig.do
- woorank.com
- quantcast.com
- qirina.com
- aolstalker.com
- seobility.net
- statsnode.com
- prlog.ru
- keywordspy.com
- seoprofiler.com
- statscrop.com
- websitesalike.com
- ppfinder.com
- sourcetool.com
- zibb.com

There are handfuls more but they get trashy fast. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Similar question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95472/are-backlinks-from-whois-ip-checker-or-similar-sites-bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Low quality is not always considered thin content or non-relevant*

Google's algorithm for determining low quality links is extremely complex than just assuming the link is not relevant or thin on content, of course the majority of the time a link from a site that is not relevant and thin will be considered low quality but this isn't necessary always the case.

*Google uses link profiling*

While we don't know Google's secret sauce when it comes to working out how quality a link is what we do know and repeatably Google have said both linking in and linking out can help rankings, it has also been said that often quality sites will often have a similar link profile to that of their competition, so with this said we should assume or believe lightly that having a similar link profile to that of the top ranking site within the same niche will benefit our rankings.

*With that said... link profiles and natural link diversity is important*

Now with that said the likes of many top websites do not need to actively remove auto generated links from woorank, pingdom and so on, in fact these should be expected and its likely that most other websites have these type of links, removing these links can change your link diversity.. for example you removing no follow links from alexa, woorank will increase your dofollow links, anchor texts and so on... therefor changing your link profile.

*What disavow was designed for...*

It's important to know why disavow came about, basically as you most likely know Google invented evil panda and penguin that punished millions of websites for low quality pages and backlinks, Google released disavow for webmasters for those users affected by penguin and not those trying who believed they were infected, in fact removing links could actually damage your rankings even through you consider the link low quality.

*Disavow is for punished websites not for shaping your link profile*

So disavow is designed for websites that at some point have feeled Google's wrath, its not designed for webmasters to gain better rankings by removing links they believe might not be helping. In fact most auto generated links such as the ones you listed could be considered 'natural' because its likely that 99% of websites have links from those sites therefor removing it becomes unnatural... not to say your get punished but a good saying is if something ain't broke, don't fix it.

*When to use the disavow tool*

- If you site has engaged in Blog Comment Spam
- If you site has engaged in Forum Siganture Spam
- If you site has engaged in Forum Field Spam
- If you site has engaged in Forum Profile Spam
- If you site has engaged in Apache Access Log Spam
- If you site has engaged in PDF Spam
- If you site has engaged in Guest Blog Spam
- If you site has engaged in Mass Directory Spam
- If you site has engaged in Social Media Spam
- If you site has engaged in Article Spam
- If you site has engaged in Link Exchanges
- If you site has engaged in Web2.0 Spam
- If you site has engaged in Linking Pyramid Schemes
- If you site has engaged in anything on a big scale that Google will believe you or someone else has attempted to manipulate your search results using black hat linking schemas

Comment: Google does know these types of sites and discounts the effect. Little value? Little effect. However, Google also knows that a portion of your link profile will consist on not only these sites but others of a different stripe. My competition may have 300,000 links, but they are from junk sites like the ones you mentioned and other similar. I do not stop the links, but I do limit what they can gather and that has diminished the creation of some links particularly from content scraper sites which has reduced some SEO losses due to keyword competition. I like the way you think!

Comment: Nice writeup and clarification, thanks. I like the idea of the natural link diversity. Agree with what you said about all sites having these links. I will leave the popular ones :)