# Are backlinks from Whois/IP checker or similar sites bad?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

I have been looking for an answer to this question for quite some time now. I am confused about backlinks coming from some of these domains. Some of them come from Whois/IP checker sites, and some of them come from social aggregator or hashtags parser sites.

```
 Domain/IP Check
 -----------------
 webstatsdomain.org
 sitegur.com
 whoislookupdb.com
 check-my-ip.net
 domainchecktool.net
 qirina.com
 similarto.us
 webstats7.net
 f2x.net

 Some sort of social aggregator
 -----------------
 snip.ly
 lakako.com
 upflow.co

 Hashtags
 -----------------
 twubs.com
 isocialtalk.com
 hashtrax.com

 Not sure
 -----------------
 news-2016.ga
 ggll.org
 prlog.ru
 jp0.ru
```

Are these bad links? Should I disavow them? Is there any issue disavowing these links?

OR should I just ignore them? Please suggest.

Comment: Here is another good answer to this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/71463/38958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All links have some value even minute amounts including nofollow links. However, if the links come from a site/page that is fully egregious, then you may want to consider disavowing them.

Google considers whois sites as a whole as low quality, however, not all whois sites are considered junk. This is also true for the various aggregator sites. They may be junk in your eyes, but not junky enough in Google's eyes. To know where a site stands is to see if it suffers a penalty. If so, then disavow the links from that site. If not, then consider if you think the site falls below your personal level of tolerance. For example, the site really really sucks while others do not suck as bad. (sorry if I broke a few rules here)

*Generally speaking, these links are fine though not great.*

I found one well ranking/performing site, the domain has since been deleted, that only had links from two sites; 36,000 from one site and just a bit less from another. There was about 6 or so organic links. Both linking sites were pure junk. However, sites that link out and receiving links from these sites can have value, albeit small per link. Promiscuous linking, low quality links, and the like, can still build rank and pass rank. Just in much smaller doses. Still, it adds up.

One company famously stated their philosophy as, I'd rather get pennies from many people than nickles from less. It is easier for someone to give up a penny than a nickle. (paraphrasing - not an exact quote)

There seems to be an argument as to whether nofollow links pass value or not. Google as misinformed us in the pass. Some would say outright lied. Some Googlers have contradicted themselves within just a few minutes. The up-shot is that nofollow does still seem to provide some value regardless of what has been said by Google. I have seen evidence that this is a true statement. Nofollow or not, I would treat every link as if they were follow. It is far safer that way.

***So, are these links bad? Likely not. But some may be.***

***Should I disavow them? Likely not. But for sites that Google thinks are beyond the pale, consider it.***

Answer (score 0):

Most of these links should be `nofollow`, so they would neither harm nor do any good. If you find any link that is not `nofollow`, you might consider disavowing them (just to be safe)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: To be more precise:

***Are these links bad?*** **No**, these links are not 'bad' per se. These links are generated when a URL is passed through these checkers for analysis purposes. Moreover, links from these sites come with a `nofollow` attribute which renders these links worthless for Google. You may safely ignore these links.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest blocking them by using Google disavow tool. The links are not relevant to your website so it is not going add any value to your search engine ranking. Also, some of them are very low quality websites. It is better to get rid of these sites before google penalize you.

Also, You will not see any negative effect of these links instantly but in long run the links are not beneficial for your website.